# How to get id in gridview from list

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

            query.Lists = "<Lists>" +
                          "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("StaffNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                          "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("CompanyNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                          "<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("ManagementNews").ID.ToString() + " />" +
                          "</Lists>";

            query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Attachments\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Authors\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Link\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Contents\" />" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Categories\" />" +
                               "<FieldRef Name=\"Date1\" Nullable=\"TRUE\"/>";

            query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

            query.RowLimit = 5;

            DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

            DetailsView1.DataSource = dv;
            DetailsView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Label1.Text = x.Message;
        }
    }
```

[image] 
I am displaying the title and date in a gridview when i click the linkbutton i want it to show that information in a detailview. i am using a visual webpart.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you do:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then, in your code behind:

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
        var listItemID = btn.CommandArgument;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have updated in the top.

Comment: So where I've got the CommandArgument= bla bla above, just add ID Which is the List Item id.
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'

Comment: ok! should i add CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' in the hyperlinkbutton?

Comment: Yes. And not a HyperLinkButton, but a LinkButton.. Like so:

<asp:LinkButton Text="text" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

Comment: like this  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"   onclick="LinkButton1_Click"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:LinkButton> what more should i write

Comment: o onclick="LinkButton1_Click" what should i write for a visual webpart

Comment: I've updated the code behind which you should use above since you are using a LinkButton.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put your UniqueId to CommandeArgument of the buton and get it back when link button is clicked? Once you get your value you just split this using SPFieldLookupValue and get your ID to filter:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("UniqueId")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

in the click event:

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton) sender;
SPFieldLookupValue f = new SPFieldLookupValue(lb.CommandArgument);
string itemID = f.LookupValue;
```

Do not forget to make a field reference to get UniqueId using CAML:

```
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"Authors\" />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"Link\" />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"Contents\" />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"_Category\" />" +
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"UniqueId\" />" +
                             "<FieldRef Name=\"Date1\" Nullable=\"TRUE\"/>";
```

Hope it helps,

Andrew